# C++ Builder TRestRequest with Unicode parameter

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I am using TRestRequest to get data from a server. I need to fill a parameter with a Unicode string value: *"ôpen"*. However, I get a crash calling Execute with this Unicode string as a query parameter.

My code :

```
    RESTRequest->ResetToDefaults();
    RESTRequest->AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 ", TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkHTTPHEADER);
    //  Get Indexing Status
    RESTRequest->Resource = "XXX/collection1"+ Form1->teReuqestHandler->Text+"?";
    RESTRequest->Method = rmGET;
    // replace all space in name field with '\ '
    UnicodeString lcQuery = Form1->teQuery->Text; // this value should be support french language or ...
    // Body
    RESTRequest->AddParameter("q",lcQuery, TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkGETorPOST);
    // Run
    String str1 = RESTRequest->GetFullRequestURL();
    RESTRequest->Execute(); // here when pass "ôpen" to lcQuery, it crash
```

How do I correctly  add *"ôpen"* to my URL?

Comment: You should encode your URL parameters with UTF-8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/306934/937125

Comment: Utf8Encode can't solve the problem!

Comment: use `UrlEncode(Utf8Encode(Text))`. you also did not specify which version of c++builder you use. is the Text unicode (WideString)?

Comment: the environement is embarcadero C++ XE5... the texte is UnicodeString..

Comment: Dest = UTF8Encode(Form1->teQuery->Text);          RESTRequest->AddParameter("q", TIdURI::URLEncode(Dest), TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkGETorPOST); // it crash in URLEncode

Comment: @DevDev Why can't you use UTF8 as kobik suggests? It's Unicode, and URL-encodeable...

Comment: What is "a crash"? What is the exact error / exception etc? Does it give you a stack trace, and if so what is it?

Comment: @DavidM when i use this : `RESTRequest->AddParameter("q", TIdURI::URLEncode(UTF8Encode(lcQuery)), TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkGETorPOST);` I get this exception : ** EIdURIException with message 'Protocol field is empty** !

Comment: @DevDev Are you sure the problem is the text you are passing? I mean, if you pass something without any special characters, say, "open", does it work? For the exception you are getting it would seem the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Thx @RodrigoGómez when i pass "open", i get some error exception    `Protocol field is empty`

Comment: with debug mode it raise exception in the file IdUri.pas :     `if FProtocol = '' then begin
    raise EIdURIException.Create(RSURINoProto);
  end;`

Comment: This is telling you that you need to specify that property. It doesn't have anything to do with the params or encoding. Are you sure the Resource is complete? I haven't used the TRestRequest object, but for the code it seems that you are missing the URL itself to query, which would include the protocol (HTTP, etc)

Comment: @DevDev: Your `TIdURI` examples are wrong. `TIdURI` handles the UTF-8 encoding for you (in fact, UTF-8 is its default encoding), so *DO NOT* manually encode the input strings to UTF-8 beforehand. Also, `TIdURI::URLEncode()` is the wrong method to use in this situation. It expects a full URL, which `teQuery` does not contain. Use `TIdURI::ParamsEncode()` instead: `RESTRequest->AddParameter(L"q", TIdURI::ParamsEncode(Form1->teQuery->Text), TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkGETorPOST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` HTTP header has no meaning in a `GET` request, only in a `POST` request.

Embarcadero's REST framework does not handle non-ASCII charsets correctly.  Even though it uses Indy internally, it does not utilize Indy's charset handling.  As such, in order to send UTF-8 encoded data, you have to either:

1. encode a `UnicodeString` to UTF-8 manually and then put the UTF-8 octets back into a `UnicodeString` so `TRESTRequest` can send them:

   ```cpp
   UnicodeString EncodeAsUtf8(const UnicodeString &s)
   {
       UTF8String utf8 = s;
       UnicodeString ret;
       ret.SetLength(utf8.Length());
       for (int x = 1; x <= utf8.Length(); ++x)
           ret[x] = (WideChar) utf8[x];
       return ret;
   }

   ...

   RESTRequest->ResetToDefaults();
   RESTRequest->Method = rmGET;
   RESTRequest->Resource = L"XXX/collection1" + Form1->teReuqestHandler->Text;
   RESTRequest->AddParameter(L"q", EncodeAsUtf8(Form1->teQuery->Text), TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkGETorPOST);
   String str1 = RESTRequest->GetFullRequestURL();
   RESTRequest->Execute();
   ```
2. encode the parameter data yourself:

   ```cpp
   #include <IdGlobal.hpp>
   #include <IdURI.hpp>

   RESTRequest->ResetToDefaults();
   RESTRequest->Method = rmGET;
   RESTRequest->Resource = L"XXX/collection1" + Form1->teReuqestHandler->Text;
   RESTRequest->AddParameter(L"q", TIdURI::ParamsEncode(Form1->teQuery->Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8), TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkGETorPOST, TRESTRequestParameterOptions() << TRESTRequestParameterOption::poDoNotEncode);
   String str1 = RESTRequest->GetFullRequestURL();
   RESTRequest->Execute();
   ```

   Or:

   ```cpp
   #include <IdGlobal.hpp>
   #include <IdURI.hpp>

   RESTRequest->ResetToDefaults();
   RESTRequest->Method = rmGET;
   RESTRequest->Resource = L"XXX/collection1" + Form1->teReuqestHandler->Text + L"?q={q}";
   RESTRequest->AddParameter(L"q", TIdURI::ParamsEncode(Form1->teQuery->Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8), TRESTRequestParameterKind::pkURLSEGMENT, TRESTRequestParameterOptions() << TRESTRequestParameterOption::poDoNotEncode);
   String str1 = RESTRequest->GetFullRequestURL();
   RESTRequest->Execute();
   ```

Otherwise, switch to Indy's `TIdHTTP` component:

```cpp
UnicodeString Response = IdHTTP1->Get(L"http://server/XXX/collection1" + Form1->teReuqestHandler->Text + L"?q=" + TIdURI::ParamsEncode(Form1->teQuery->Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8));
```

Comment: Using Indy directly seems by far the easiest option here

Comment: hard to believe that in 2015 Embarcadero are still coming out with non-Unicode-enabled APIs